# Adding Smart Switch When Neutrals Used as Travelers in Three-way Switch

Tags: smart-switch

Is there a way to install standard smart three-way switches in a box where the electrician used the neutral from the breaker box as a traveler?

I have a three-way switch with the Neutrals in the box, but this is the load switch (shorts the circuit, when I connect the Neutral wire to the switch), and the line switch uses the Neutral wire as one of the Travelers! The line switch is configured in a two-gang box with another three-way switch (I would like to replace that one, too). Can I pig-tail the Line (or Neutral) wire from the adjacent switch to the Neutral for the smart switch? Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt that anything actually used **neutral wire as one of the travelers**. That simply isn't a thing. It doesn't work that way. What I suspect you mean is **I have a cable with black/white/red and the white wire is a traveler instead of neutral**. Which can absolutely happen because **neutral is (almost) always white, but white is NOT neutral**. US cables come in black/white and black/white/red. So if you have a 2-wire connection (e.g., 240V-only device such as a water heater) then white will be a hot wire. And if you have a 3-wire connection such as a 3-way switch then you can

Comment: easily end up with white being something other than neutral. It is not "neutral is not neutral", it is "**white** is not neutral". Big difference. Not to fix this: **Please upload pictures showing how all of the wires connect to each of the 3-way switches.**

Comment: Note also that while most (not all, but most) smart switches require neutral, *some* smart switches only require one traveler rather than two, which can often free up the white wire to be used as a neutral wire. There are **many** variations - starting point is to see existing wiring and, if you have already picked out a line of smart switches, information about the smart switches.

Comment: Neutral must be white or gray. But white wires in cables are NOT always neutral. A traveler is NOT Neutral, and being white does not MAKE it Neutral. Erase that false equivalence from your thinking and you'll live longer.

Comment: Those aren't neutrals. This problem is much harder than you want it to be.  Partly because smart 3-ways are themselves complicated, and you can't use a 1-way smart switch on them, and you don't get to choose where the smart switch "master" goes.   I would suggest hook it back the way you found it, assure that it does work properly, then take a lot of pix and add a lot of detail, and we can then advise.  As is, this is non-answerable except to tell you this.